# How can I add images into a TComboBox in VCL?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to have a TComboBox with images instead of text. Is this possible? If yes, then how? I've looked over all of the properties a dozen times and I can't find anything. Also, I'm very new to Delphi. So maybe this is obvious, but I couldn't find a place to add images into a ComboBox instead of text. How can I add images to my ComboBox?

I tried looking online for help, but nothing really helped or nothing that was easy enough for me to understand.

Comment: Why not use a `TComboBoxEx`?

Comment: I did not know about TComboBoxEx. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `TComboBox`, you can set its [`Style`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomComboBox.Style) property to one of the `OwnerDraw` options, and then use its [`OnDrawItem`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomComboBox.OnDrawItem) event to draw your images.

Or, as Andreas Rejbrand mentioned, you can use [`TComboBoxEx`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TComboBoxEx) instead. Put your images in an `ImageList` assigned to its [`Images`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomComboBoxEx.Images) property, and then  assign an [`ImageIndex`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ListActns.TListControlItem.ImageIndex) to each item in its [`ItemsEx`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomComboBoxEx.ItemsEx) property.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a code example or a tutorial for the Owner Draw options?

Comment: @MartinKakhuis just use websearch for this